# Why does switching order of OR statement fix TypeError: '<=' not supported between 'str' and 'int'?

Tags: python, validation, types, logic, typeerror

I am doing some basic data validation, and I'm confused. I have the following function:

```
def is_int_gt2(num):
    if num <= 2 or type(num) != int:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

When I call `is_int_gt2(-1)` I get `False`. And when I call `is_int_gt2(5)` I get `True`. So far so good. But if I call `is_int_gt2('a')`, I get `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

What confuses me, however is that when I switch the order of the conditions in the `or` statement, the function works perfectly!:

```
def is_int_gt2(num):
    if type(num) != int or num <= 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

So now I have a working function, but I don't know why. *Why does switching the order of the condition fix the function?* Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code block, the `num <= 2` expression comes first. When you pass in `'a'`, python tries to compare `'a'` and `2` using `<=`, resulting in the error.

But when `type(num) != int` is first, python checks first the type of `a`, which is `str`. And since `str != int`, the expression is `True`, breaking out of the `if` statement; never checking if it was `<= 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is answered by @Have a nice day, but i would suggest using a try and except block instead

```
try:
    if num > 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
except TypeError:
    return False
```

This way the code is much cleaner as you dont have the issue where simply changing the order of comparison produces an error. It handles the case properly and also is easy to understand

**Edit:** For a better understanding of the `or` operator , refer [How to use the Python or operator](https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/#how-the-python-or-operator-works)

The behaviour described by you is because of short circuit evaluation

Quoting the source:
"Short-Circuit Evaluation
Python can sometimes determine the truth value of a Boolean expression before it has evaluated all the subexpressions and objects involved. The Python or operator, for instance, stops evaluating operands as soon as it finds something that’s considered true. For example, the following expression is always True:

```
>>> True or 4<3
True
```

If the first operand in an or expression evaluates to true, regardless of the value of the second operand (4 < 3 is False), then the expression is considered to be true, and the second operand is never evaluated. This is called short-circuit (lazy) evaluation."

**EDIT 2:**
'After reading your comment about performance.'
I used the `timeit` module to check the two methods and the results are as follows:

CASE 1: `num=1`

```
----------------------
num = 1
try except method
time taken is: 0.24674580000000002
----------------------
num = 1
if else method
time taken is: 0.3399378
```

remark: try except method is better

CASE 2: `num = 3`

```
----------------------
num = 3
try except method
time taken is: 0.2548527
----------------------
num = 3
if else method
time taken is: 0.5341225000000001
```

remark: try except method is better

CASE 3: `num = "a"`

```
----------------------
num = 'a'
time taken is: 1.2462476
----------------------
num = 'a'
time taken is: 0.3462103999999999
```

remark: if else method is better.

**CONCLUSION:** it is clear that the try except method is faster except for when the exception is actually caught. So as long as num is an integer, try except is better, but if num is not an integer, then if else method would be much better. Upto you to decide which one you would want to use

**NOTE:** The time given here is specific to my system. it would probably be slightly different for your system. And the time mentioned here is the best time in a million (1000000) loops of each method

Comment: Does the try except block reduce performance meaningfully? Is it slower than the or statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the function design aspect - Return False or allow Exception ?**

In my opinion, it would not be correct to return `False` when input is not `int`. Comparing 'a' with 2 does not make sense because there is no way to compare them.

Hence, it is better to have the exception `TypeError` rather than returning `False`.

Also, going by the function name `is_int_gt2()`, it expects an `int`. Hence, the function can assume the input in `int`. In case, it is not `int`, an exception is raised.

Suppressing the exception and returning `False` could hide potential bugs in the application that uses this function.

Simplified code would be:

```
def is_int_gt2(num):
    if num <= 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```